# How to set up Phantomjs behind nginx

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nginx, phantomjs

I'm working on SEO for my angular app and I'm using PhantomJS to render html when it is a crawler. 
For some reason I get a 501 when I do `http://aaaaa.com/?_escaped_fragment=/home`
But I get my page when I do `http://aaaaa.com`

This tells me that it's probably by nginx config file that isn't routing properly.

Here is my nginx config (at least the snippet):

```
  #mi angular app
        server {

                location / {

                        if ($args ~ _escaped_fragment_) {
                                 proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
                                 break;
                        }
                        root /var/www/html/miwebapp/client/app;
                }
        }
```

Here is the command I use to run phantomjs:

```
phantomjs --disk-cache=no angular-seo-server.js 8888 http://localhost:8000/home
```

When I run it, I get:

```
Listening on 8888...
Press Ctrl+C to stop.
```

So phantom starts, but requests fail... Any thoughts?

Comment: What do the nginx error logs show when this happens?

Comment: I just started using nginx 1 day ago. I didn't realize it has logs. Where are they saved? Is there a way to print to the console?

Comment: @WilliamFalcon - wrong place to ask about nginx logs - but `cat /var/log/nginx/error.log`

Answer (score 2):

This is my configure:

```html
if ($args ~ _escaped_fragment_) {
    rewrite ^ /snapshot$uri;
}

location ~ ^/snapshot(.*) {
    rewrite ^/snapshot(.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
}
```

more info here: https://github.com/liuwenchao/ajax-seo

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to utilize named locations somehow?